# Extrato de horas online por dia

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso extrair da tabela RADACCT abastecida por freeradius, servidor de Radius com MySQL, os registros de conexões de determinado usuário, de cada dia do mês, para determinar quantas horas naquele dia o usuário ficou efetivamente online.

A dificuldade que encontrei referia-se à data e hora(datetime) de início em um dia e à data e hora(datetime) de término no outro dia ou vários dias após o início da sessão. Com os cálculos e códigos que fiz, sempre faltam ou passam minutos e horas!

A tabela abaixo foi encurtada, e esta apenas com os campos que preciso para os cálculos!

Abaixo está um exemplo da tabela:

```
id | username | starttime           | stoptime            | totalsessiontime(use gmdate to return total)
1  | test     | 2019-03-31 16:28:43 | 2019-04-02 19:34:19 | 183935
2  | test     | 2019-04-02 19:35:17 | 2019-04-04 16:28:43 | 183935
```

O resultado que preciso é assim:

```
Day        | Total
2019-03-31 | 07:31:17
2019-04-01 | 24:00:00
2019-04-02 | 23:59:02
2019-04-03 | 24:00:00
2019-04-04 | 16:28:43
```

Os resultados podem não estar corretos, eu fiz de cabeça um exemplo para ser o mais fiel possível.

Já fiz várias buscas, mas os casos que encontro são muito específicos, como os meus, e só não consigo interpretar para implementar uma QUERY.

**Query usada:**

```php
    SELECT SUM(acctsessiontime) as sessiontime,date(acctstarttime) as data_inicio, date(acctstoptime) as data_fim,time(acctstarttime) as time_inicio, time(acctstoptime) as time_fim FROM radacct WHERE username = '$usuario' AND (date(acctstarttime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' AND (date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' OR date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia_seguinte')
```

**Controller**

```php
    function consumo() {

        $this->load->model('radius_model');

        $tempo_online = $this->radius_model->tempo_online('usuario@test', '04', '2019');

        foreach ($tempo_online as $dia => $value) {
            $dias[' ' . $dia . '-04-2019 '] = gmdate("H:i:s", (int) $tempo_online[$dia]['sessiontime']);
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($dias); }
```

**Model**

```php
    public function tempo_mensal_online($usuario, $dia, $mes, $ano) {

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(acctsessiontime) as sessiontime,date(acctstarttime) as data_inicio, date(acctstoptime) as data_fim,time(acctstarttime) as time_inicio, time(acctstoptime) as time_fim FROM radacct WHERE username = '$usuario' AND (date(acctstarttime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' AND (date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' OR date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia_seguinte')";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: E você não fez nenhuma query?

Comment: Você pode utilizar os cálculos em horas e datas usando as próprias [funções do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: @ngueno Excelente, já vou estudar isso !!

Comment: Fiz uma query:

`$this->db->select("SUM(acctsessiontime) as sessiontime,date(acctstarttime) as data_inicio, date(acctstoptime) as data_fim,time(acctstarttime) as time_inicio, time(acctstoptime) as time_fim");
//        $this->db->from("radacct");
//        $this->db->where("username = '$usuario'");
//        $this->db->where("date(acctstarttime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' AND (date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia' OR date(acctstoptime) = '$ano-$mes-$dia_seguinte')");
//        return $this->db->get()->row_array();`

Mas não consegui chegar ao resultado acima..

Comment: Outra dica é tentar com queries SQL nativas antes de colocar na aplicação, fica mais fácil para descobrir o erro e ajuda a gente a te ajudar também :)

Comment: Caro Onurb, bem-vindo! Transferi sua edição para o campo abaixo. É muito bom que você tenha retornado com seu feedback para a comunidade. Para próximas perguntas, dê uma lida em "O que é um [mcve]", o que pode ajudar muito a viabilizar os posts. Há de se reconhecer que você fez boas melhorias no seu post, ela só peca por excesso de informação que não influi no centro do problema (o link mencionado pode ajudar nesse sentido). A proposta do site é de que as perguntas sirvam como repositório de conhecimento para futuros visitantes, então é muito importante que se restrinjam ao núcleo do problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub><sup>resposta elaborada pelo autor da pergunta, transcrita para cá</sup></sub>

---

Após ler a documentação do MySQL enviada por @ngueno, consegui chegar ao resultado esperado modificando minha Query e tratando o resultado com cálculos de datas.

Segue abaixo como ficaram os códigos:

**Nova Query**

```php
    SELECT acctsessiontime, acctstarttime, acctstoptime FROM radacct WHERE username = '$usuario' AND ('$ano-$mes-$dia' BETWEEN date(acctstarttime) AND date(acctstoptime) OR '$ano-$mes-$dia' BETWEEN date(acctstoptime) AND date(acctstarttime))
```

O resultado só foi satisfatório usando a operador BETWEEN([Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)), consegui extrair os registros corretos e assim fazer cálculos que deram o resultado que preciso.

**Novo Controller**

```php
function consumo() {
        $this->load->model('radius_model');

        $usuario = 'usuario@test';
        $mes = '04';
        $ano = '2019';
        $ultimo_dia_mes = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, '01', $ano));


        for ($dia = 01; $dia <= $ultimo_dia_mes; $dia++) {
            strlen($dia) === 1 ? $dia = '0' . $dia : ''; // add 0 aos dias 1-9

            /*  Buscando registros diarios do usuário */
            $registros_diario = $this->radius_model->tempo_online($usuario, $dia, $mes, $ano);

            if (count($registros_diario) > 0) {

                /*  Descobrindo o primeiro e ultimo item da array de registros */
                $primeiro = reset($registros_diario);
                $ultimo = end($registros_diario);

                $primeiro_acct = strtotime($primeiro['acctstarttime']);
                $sessao_inicio = strtotime("$ano-$mes-$dia 00:00:00");
                $primeira_diferenca = $sessao_inicio - $primeiro_acct;

                $sessao_fim = strtotime("$ano-$mes-$dia 24:00:00");
                $ultimo_acct = strtotime($ultimo['acctstoptime']);
                $segunda_diferenca = $ultimo_acct - $sessao_fim;

                /*  Descobrindo o tempo online total */
                $soma = 0;
                foreach ($registros_diario as $registro) {
                    $soma += $registro['acctsessiontime'];
                }

                $soma_final = $soma - ($primeira_diferenca + $segunda_diferenca);

                $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
                $dtT = new \DateTime("@$soma_final");
                $horas_online = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h:%i:%s');
                if ($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a') > 0) {
                    $horas_online = '24:00:00';
                }

                $registros[$dia] = $horas_online;
            }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($registros);
    }
```

**Nova Model**

```php
public function tempo_online($usuario, $dia, $mes, $ano) {

        $this->db->select("acctsessiontime, acctstarttime, acctstoptime");

        $this->db->where("username = '$usuario' AND ('$ano-$mes-$dia' BETWEEN date(acctstarttime) AND date(acctstoptime) OR '$ano-$mes-$dia' BETWEEN date(acctstoptime) AND date(acctstarttime))");

        return $this->db->get('radacct')->result_array();
    }
```